# where is the last commands file

Tags: debian-lenny

When using the command line as root in Debian I get last commands executed as root. 
Where are those saved, what is the default file path and how can I find it?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using bash (default shell in Debian) you can see all your recent history in the file `~/.bash_history` (so .bash_history file in your local user)

Also from the command line you can type `history` and it'll also show you all your recent command history

Comment: Note that the file will not be updated immediately with default setting, but after closing the shell (bash in this case).

Comment: is there also a log with the full history?

Comment: Unfortunately not, unless you configure bash for doing so it'll cut off your history. You can decide how many lines of history you get by adding this to your `~/.bashrc` file `export HISTSIZE=10000` (in this case I get 10,000 lines of bash history)

Answer (score 9):

The file you want is:
`/root/.bash_history`

Comment: Haha, you beat me twice by 2 seconds, good answer sir ;)

Answer (score 3):

What others have said about .bash_history is right and proper, but it won't pick up commands executed as root with sudo.  Those will be in the individual users' `~/.bash_history` files (or other files, if they use other shells than bash).

Answer (score 2):

Executing command with space in front, wont store command in history also.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but it's a really nice trick. Thanks, learned something new today :)

Comment: @user68884 interesting

Comment: This can be controlled using the `HISTCONTROL` variable.